# HTML5 FileSystem API Android Chrome access to sdcard

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, filesystems, html5-filesystem

I am trying to create an HTML5 Application that is able to access a large amount of files. Therefore I looked at the FileSystem API to be able to read files from local filesystem.

I did a PoC using phonegap File API, and all worked as expected, I was able to produce similar results using the FileSystem API on Chrome Desktop...

However I am faced with a serious issue, while I can access my filesystem in Desktop, I can't access sdcard from Android Chrome. I tried to use this demo:

http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/filesystem/filer.js/demos/index.html

I can select files from my local system in desktop: My Pictures, etc... But I can't do the same with Android Chrome

How can i access the device filesystem /sdcard in Android Chrome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this article on HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/):

*It's important to remember that this file system is sandboxed, meaning one web app cannot access another app's files. This also means you cannot read/write files to an arbitrary folder on the user's hard drive (for example My Pictures, My Documents, etc.).*

The FileSystem API was designed to allow your app to create and manipulate files which will persist between usages of your application.  It cannot be used to expose arbitrary files from outside of it's sandbox.

Alternatively, the [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) can be used to read, though not modify, files from the entire system.  However, File API cannot be used to read arbitrary files on the system.  It's usage is based on HTMLs `<input type=file>` tag, where the user must explicitly input the File to be read.

The above applies to an app running in Android Chrome the same as it does to Desktop Chrome, so you're out of luck unless the user is willing to use the input to grant access to the files you desire.  However, you mentioned you also attempted a PoC using PhoneGap.  The [PhoneGap File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html), though mostly acting as a wrapper around the HTML5 implementation, has some subtle differences, mainly in that it does allow for access to arbitrary files on the SD card.  When using the API call `window.requestFileSystem()`, your success callback will have one argument, a [FileSystem](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileSystem) object, where the `root` property is a reference to the /sdcard folder.  This can be used to traverse your sdcard and create FileReaders and FileWriters anywhere within.

Comment: Hi Matt, I read that article as well, I understand it is a sandboxed fs. However in desktop I am able to select files from My Pictures, and My Documents and whatever. You can try it yourself with the link that I posted. In Android I can't select directories correctly but I was able to select files. And the PhoneGAP PoC that I did I was able to read directories from the sdcard. I was able to create DirectoryReader without much issue. I was able to replicate that PoC in Chrome Desktop with the FileSystem API, but I am unable to do so with the Android Chrome version. This is very frustrating

Comment: I see. Just for a bit more clarification, is the issue you're having that you're unable to select directories at all on Android, or that there was a problem with the DirectoryReader after a directory was selected? Also, is the demo that you posted the code that you're doing this testing with over all platforms?

Comment: I am unable to select directories at all in Android. The demo is the same on all platforms.

Comment: There are some issues with File API on mobile chrome, I have performed more research and found a solution to the issue by creating a repository of files and download them to the permanent sandboxed filesystem. So far it's working, need to create more complex scenarios to make sure this is a usable system, but so far so good.